# Refresh div with table dynamically without jQuery or other frameworks

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Long story short I am using javascript and php to add / remove questions to a database (think notecards to study with).  It all works except I can't get the table on my page to refresh whenever I hit the add question button which uses a XHR to add the data.  I can refresh the page manually and see the updated table with my information, but want to use ajax to refresh the table on-screen right after I submit the new question (or delete it) seamlessly.  I would rather not have to redraw the entire page, just the table and the info.  I understand how to use the XHR and refresh the mysql...but how can I tell the browser to reload a table in a specific div on the page - and only that specific table - with the additional or removed info?

I can NOT use Jquery or other frameworks, just plain old JS, PHP, and html.

I have been searching, and just can't get that "ah-ha" moment yet, can't anybody help me out and push me in the right direction?  Generalities, Dom commands to look up or research would be a great help, I don't need character by character coding done by the collective.

thank you, :-)

Comment: why not just use the data you send via xhr to regenerate the page? if not you can always just do an new xhr request after submit? what did you try and why did it fail?

Comment: +1 for wanting to understand how it all works (although I do suggest you use jquery or another framework if you have to have cross-browser support, it tends to be easier)

Comment: I can redraw the whole page, but I am trying to learn the XHR technique, and if I redraw the entire page won't I be giving up the advantage of the seemless ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at `innerHTML` you can place your table inside a div or whatever, and use innerHTML to regenerate the contents of that div.

Comment: So I could have a div with a table in it, and then redraw the table with something (ignore the lack of coding syntax) like div.innerHTML = "redraw the entire table".  If going in this direction would it be best to initially populate it the same way?  thanks for help.

Comment: you can populate it the same way, but it could also be static content from the start, that gets replaced when the action happens.  here is a good basic example of how to do it http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is get it with a method such as `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector`. Then you could change the element however you would need to.

```
var element = document.querySelector('#elToChange');
element.innerHTML = //something from the server
element.remove(); //for deleting

//If you delete remember to do the following so that you don't have a memory leak.
delete element;
```

Comment: if going in this direction would I remove the table and leave the containing div yes?  If I remove the table using .remove as you suggested would I have to use append child to add the refreshed table or would innerHTML suffice? thank you for responding.

Comment: `delete element;` shouldn't be necessary.  Once the JS leaves scope, it's up for garbage collection, isn't it?

Comment: @MattCronin If you use `.remove()`, then `#elToChange` is no longer on the page - so don't use it if you just want to update the html inside `#elToChange`

Comment: If you delete the element, but keep a reference to the element in javascript, you will have a memory leak.

Comment: You wouldn't have to use a div. You could just use querySelector to get part of the table. See the [node page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)